# iPhone alert an alarm if stolen

Tags: iphone, security, alarm

We are developing an enterprise application .The phones are connected to a Wifi router. The objective is to trigger an alarm if the phone moves out of the secure area .. (outside the building)
What is the best way to check if the iPhone is always inside the building .

some of the options we tried are

1.using Wifi(continous ping to wifi network),if not trigger an alarm .
2.if coordinates change (using GPS)

Are there any other means to achieve this .

Comment: I cant think of any other input the phone has about its surroundings. You might be able to do a movement based thing that triggers when the phone is touched, but that would make the phone unusable. The two methods you listed are probably the best, first go for the GPS, then the WiFi option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Location Services in iOS 4 (with the background location feature) to determine when the phone has moved to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

@indragie's idea of using Location Services is a good one. If you can be sure that the WIFI SID isn't going to change, you could probe to see which access point the iPhone is currently associated to. If you are going to ping, then a better approach is to make the system service agnostic, and simply issue an HTTP query on a regular basis to your enterprise server. The server can then have a policy language on it declaring acceptable access points (from a variety of metrics). This might be set up to allow people to take their iPhones home.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is GPS as the phone will not be able to find its location if you rely on WiFi and the device is not connected to a WiFi network.

Check out Apple's documentation for Location Awareness capabilities here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

You will be able to track "significant" or standard location changes in the background, details can be found here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5

[edit to include]
This might be of interest to you too - http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. Just to let the iPhone user know that he/she is moving away, using Location Services is good enough.

However, if you want to have a server that makes sure all the devices are within range, then it's more complex because your application may get suspended without a notice from a background state; in other words, you may not be able to catch the moment when your application terminates and take appropriate actions. Therefore you are going to need a heartbeat system like pinging to the server in this case.